# postgres remove json object from json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using postgres 12.X, I have the following logs table :-

> logs
> id bigint ,
> jsondata text

Following are values in json

```
[
  {
    "loginfo": "somelog1",
    "id": "app1"
  },
{
    "loginfo": "somelog2",
    "id": "app2"
  }
  ]
```

I need remove all json objects from this text column where id == "app2"

tried the below as per answer here :- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84472/how-to-remove-object-from-json-array

```
UPDATE logs i SET    jsondata = i2.jsondata FROM  (SELECT id, array_to_json(array_agg(elem)) AS jsondata
  FROM   logs cand
       , json_array_elements(cand.jsondata) elem
  WHERE  cand.jsondata @> '{[{"id":"app2"}]}'::jsonb
  AND    elem->>'id' <> 'app2'
  GROUP  BY 1 ) i2
WHERE i2.id = i.id;
```

But ERROR comes as below :-

> ERROR:  function json_array_elements(text) does not exist

Comment: Your column is no defined as `jsonb` (or at least `json`)  so you need to cast it, e.g. `json_array_elements(jsondata::json)` - the best solution is to change its data type from `text` to `jsonb` using `alter table` (and then use the jsonb_xxxx functions)

Comment: Don't abuse JSON like this. Store these data in a separate table without JSON columns and have a foreign key relationship between the tables. Then the exercise becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=31104e23689a20788f0e43a51a42955c)

Why do you store JSON objects in `text` columns? In that case you need to cast it before using it as JSON:

```
SELECT
    id,
    json_agg(elems)                               -- 3
FROM mytable,
    json_array_elements(jsondata::json) as elems  -- 1
WHERE elems ->> 'id' <> 'app2'                    -- 2
GROUP BY id
```

1. Cast text into JSON; Extract the JSON array into a record per element
2. Filter the required objects
3. Reaggregate remaining elements into a new JSON array